# Is Bluetooth version of Android Device related to Android version?

Tags: android, bluetooth, version

I once wondered if can I get a specific bluetooth version of Android devices? I searched a little bit and I figured out that it's not possible.

So, I wondered something else this time. **Is bluetooth version related with Android version?** Such as:

- bluetooth 2.0 run at android 2.3.x devices and below
- bluetooth 3.0 run at android 3.x.x devices,
- bluetooth 4.0 run at android 4.x.x and above

Can I make an assumption something like that?

If I can, I'll use Android version of devices.

**Note:** By the way, I already know that I can get bluetooth type, such as **bluetooth classic** or **bluetooth low energy**.

Comment: No bluetooth version is not dependent on Android version at all. Unfortunately you cannot determine bluetooth version but you can determine if its Normal Bluetooth or Bluetooth Low Energy using this code: `PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
boolean isBT = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH);
boolean isBLE = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE);`

Comment: Yep, thank for ansver but i already know that. I just wondered if there is something else, maybe a trick (: